# JS getting value of object with key starting with a string

Tags: javascript, object, key

Is there a quick way to get the value of a key starting with a certain string?

Example :

```
var obj = {
  "key123" : 1,
  "anotherkey" : 2
}

obj['key1'] // would return 1
obj['ano'] // would return 2
```

Thanks

Comment: "quick" in terms of what - iterate over them and pick they key name that matches your requirements.

Comment: Not without iterating the object keys....what is the use case?

Comment: What would the value be for "`obj['key1']`" if you had `var obj = { "key123" : 1, "key1" : 2 }`?

Comment: @Kenney it should be the first element found in the object. In this case 1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a helper function

```
function findValueByPrefix(object, prefix) {
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property) && 
       property.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
       return object[property];
    }
  }
}

findValueByPrefix(obj, "key1");
```

As Kenney commented, the above function will return first match.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `find` on the `entries` of the object. IF there's a key which starts with, access the index at `1` to get the value.

```
Object.entries(o).find(([k,v]) => k.startsWith(part))?.[1]
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const getValue = (part, o) => Object.entries(o).find(([k, v]) => k.startsWith(part))?.[1]

const obj = {
  "key123": 1,
  "anotherkey": 2
}

console.log(
  getValue('key', obj),
  getValue('ano', obj),
  getValue('something', obj),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the first match of the property name which begins with specified string:

```
    var obj = {
        "key123": 1,
        "anotherkey": 2,
        "somekey" : 3        
    };

    function getObjectValueByPartialName(obj, name){
        if (typeof obj !== "object") {
            throw new Error("object is required!");
        }
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (prop.indexOf(name) === 0){
                return obj[prop];
            }
        }
        return "no such property!";
    }

    console.log(getObjectValueByPartialName(obj, 'some'));  // output: 3
    console.log(getObjectValueByPartialName(obj, 'key1'));  // output: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use the following one-line generic custom method

```js
var obj = {
      "key123" : 1,
      "anotherkey" : 2
    };

const getObjPropForMatchPrefixKey = (object,prefix) => Object.keys(object).filter(item => item.toString().startsWith(prefix))[0];

console.log(obj[getObjPropForMatchPrefixKey(obj,'an')]);
console.log(obj[getObjPropForMatchPrefixKey(obj,'key')]);
```