# How to check if the keys of an object starts with a specific character?

Tags: javascript

I just want to check if an object key starts with a specific prefix or not. For example:

```
var obj = {
  456: "Hello",
  512: "Bye"
}

//what I want to do with the object

if (obj.key starts with 4) {
  // do this....
} else {
  // do this...
}
```

Comment: Right, and what did you try?

Comment: Object keys are strings, what is the problem?

Comment: Yeah you are always welcome to experiment!!!

Comment: Related: [JS getting value of object with key starting with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279319)

Answer (score 14):

```
Object.keys(total).filter(k => k.startsWith('your-specific-chars'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You could get the key and test it.

```js
var object = { 456:"Hello", 512:"Bye" },
    key;
    
for (key in object) {
    if (!key.startsWith('4')) continue;
    console.log(key, object[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to convert the object into an array with the keys as its elements and iterating it you can check if the key starts with `4` using `substr` method

```js
var obj = {
  456: "Hello",
  512: "Bye"
}

Object.keys(obj)
      .forEach(e => e.substr(0, 1) == 4 ? console.log(e + ':' + obj[e]) : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**startsWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
var obj = { 456:"Hello",  512:"Bye" }

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {
  e.startsWith('4') ?  console.log('start with 4 -->', e)
                    :  console.log('Do not start with 4 -->', e)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
var obj = {
  456: "Hello",
  512: "Bye"
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.charAt(0) == 4) {
    console.log(elem, obj[elem])
  }
  //else {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read a string using indices, just like you read an array:

```js
var object = { 456 : "Hello", 512 : "Bye" };
for (var key in object) {
  if (key[0] === "4") {
    console.log(key + " starts with 4");
  } else {
    console.log(key + " does not start with 4");
  }
  console.log("object[" + key + "] gives \"" + object[key] + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var obj = { 
456:"Hello",
512:"Bye",
444:"good morning"
}


Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(key.startsWith('4'))
        console.log(key, obj[key]);

})
```

You can try this.